# change function of a button in webView

Tags: android

I load a web URL in webView. I want to change the functionality of specific button     of web.who i access to button and change its functionality?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView mWebView;
    String URl = "http://comingup.review/user";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);


        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl(URl);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

in your `WebViewClient` put a breakpoint inside `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)` and check what is the url which the webview loads when you click on the button.

```
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false; // put here breakpoint
        }
```

after you click on the button, the webview will redirect you to another url, which you will see in the breakpoint. copy this url.

after it, put this inside `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)`:

```
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (JavaUtils.equals(url, "url from button click")) {
                // do whatever you need
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
```

for example:

```
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (JavaUtils.equals(url, "about:blank")) {
            finish();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

i didn't checked it but it should work...

Comment: i cannot understand can you give me an example